# Delphi - How to copy the text from one tedit to another, while the user is typing in the first one?

Tags: delphi

There are two tedit

One is enabled for the user, and the other disabled.

The moment user types anything in the tedit, the same thing gets typed in the disabled tedit, while the user is typing.

I don't want to use any buttons for this.

How to implement this in Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the OnChange event of your first TEdit and set text of the second edit to the text of the first. This should look like

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := Edit1.Text;
end;
```